# Left join with (no rows) condition on right table

Tags: mysql

```
SHOPS
+----+------------+
| id | shop_name  |
+----+------------+

ORDERBOOKINGS
+-----+---------+-------------+------------+
| id  | shop_id | grand_total | created_at |
+-----+---------+-------------+------------+
```

I want to get a table like this:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| shop_name  | total_orders | total_amount |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The condition is that I have date filter which returns only the order total between specified dates. I want it to return all the shops (if there is no order of some shops between those dates then it should return those with total_orders as 0).

**NOTE:** Some of the shops may not even have an entry in the orderbookings table.

I have tried the following but it fails to return all rows from shops table:

```
SELECT COUNT(orderbookings.id),
       SUM(orderbookings.grand_total),
       shops.shop_name
FROM `orderbookings`
LEFT JOIN shops
    on orderbookings.shop_id = shops.id
where orderbookings.created_at BETWEEN "2015-10-22 17:02:02" AND "2017-03-07 17:02:02"
GROUP BY shops.id
```

Any idea how can I achieve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `where` to `and` in your query and `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(orderbookings.id),
    COALESCE(SUM(orderbookings.grand_total), 0),
    shops.shop_name 
FROM `orderbookings` 
RIHGT JOIN shops on orderbookings.shop_id = shops.id and orderbookings.created_at BETWEEN "2015-10-22 17:02:02" AND "2017-03-07 17:02:02" 
GROUP BY shops.id
```

Explain:
1) If you want to get all the shops, you should use `shops` as main table, then left join `orderbookings`, here I use right join cause you use `orderbookings` as main table;
2) If you use `orderbookings`'s column in `where`, left join will take as an inner join.

At last, `left join` solution will like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(orderbookings.id),
    COALESCE(SUM(orderbookings.grand_total), 0),
    shops.shop_name 
FROM `shops ` 
LEFT JOIN orderbookings on orderbookings.shop_id = shops.id and orderbookings.created_at BETWEEN "2015-10-22 17:02:02" AND "2017-03-07 17:02:02" 
GROUP BY shops.id
```

Comment: Already tried. Still returns only those shops which have an entry in the orderbookings table. Leaves all other shops.

Comment: @nikhil.malik Updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: Works now. Thanx.!

Answer (score 0):

You want to reverse your join and add some IFNULLs:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(orderbookings.id),0),
       IFNULL(SUM(orderbookings.grand_total),0),
       shops.shop_name
FROM `orderbookings`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN shops
    on orderbookings.shop_id = shops.id
       and orderbookings.created_at BETWEEN "2015-10-22 17:02:02" AND "2017-03-07 17:02:02"
GROUP BY shops.id
```

Comment: You might need to move the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.

Comment: No help. Still returns only those shops which have orders in the orderbookings table. Leaves all other shops. Do you want me to give real data.?

Comment: Whoops, join syntax is a little rusty. Trye a RIGHT OUTER JOIN. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Ilion Worked with IFNULL and moving Where to on clause. Thanx Guys